# Laravel Carbon, querying database where a field date is 2 weeks less than itself

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon, laravel-query-builder

I have a Election model, where I'm trying to write a query that will show me specific results.

The idea is pretty simple:

A Election `starting_date`, for example is 15/10/2018.

I need my query to show all `elections` that will start in next 2 weeks.

I mean, for that specific case, today is 01/10/2018, so I need all elections that will start in period `01/10/2018 - 15/10/2018`.

So, I tried to write something like:

```
public function notificationBeforeCollection() {
    return $this->activeElections()
        ->where('start_collection', '>=', Carbon::now()
        ->subDays(14)->format('Y-m-d'))
        ->where('start_collection', '<', Carbon::now()
        ->format('Y-m-d'));
}
```

But it doesn't work, and it looks like it can't work by comparing the `starting_date` with today. It looks like I need to write something like:

```
where('starting_date', '>=', 'starting_date'->subDays(14);
```

If I'm right, is there a way how to use `Carbon` against a field in query builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your actual query is looking for all elections that started 14 days ago.

You need to do something like:

```
 return $this->activeElections()->where('start_collection', '>', Carbon::today())
          ->where('start_collection', '<=' Carbon::today()->addDays(14));
```

Answer (score 2):

To get 'Elections' of two weeks from tomorrow

```
// using 'Carbon'
$start_date = Carbon::now()->addDay()->format('Y-m-d');
$end_date = Carbon::now()->addDays(14)->format('Y-m-d');

public function notificationBeforeCollection() {
    return $this->activeElections()->whereBetween(
        'start_collection', [$start_date, $end_date]
    );
}
```